# How to show PDF's table on HTML

Tags: android, html, pdf, mobile

We are having and requirement where we have to convert PDF and show them as HTML pages on Mobiles.
We have used PDf to HTML converter but some of PDF contains Table Structure. The converter just omits the table structure and shows the inner content . but we need the whole Table Structure in HTML form. We tried converting it to image, but images are coming blur so cant read from it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: AVS4YOU Software Navigator its a free converter

Answer (score 0):

Does the PDF actually contain a table structure or does it just look like a table when viewed by the human eye. If it contains marked content it will have meta data to define a table. Otherwise there is no table data

Comment: PDF contains a table structure ...just take a look at this pdf [link](http://www.marico.com/html/investor/pdf/Quarterly_Updates/Consolidated%20Financial%20Results%20-%20Q3FY11.pdf)

Comment: It is just text and lines on the page. You see a structure but this is not in the file.

Comment: my problem is i want to show the same structure on Mobile ...and it should be html format so that user don't have to download complete PDF